# Batch multiplication/division with scalar in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, batch-processing

I'm struggling to find a simple way to multiply a batch of tensors with a batch of scalars.

I have a tensor with dimensions N, 4, 4. What I want is to divide tensor in the batch with the value at position 3, 3.

For example, let's say I have:

```
A = [[[1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, a]], 
     [[1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, b]]
```

What I want is to obtain the following:

```
 B = [[[1/a, 1/a, 1/a, 0],
      [1/a, 1/a, 1/a, 0],
      [1/a, 1/a, 1/a, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1]], 
     [[1/b, 1/b, 1/b, 0],
      [1/b, 1/b, 1/b, 0],
      [1/b, 1/b, 1/b, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: So? What thing prevents you to do that? Just do it! But before you start, you should know that the arithmetic operations of `set /A` Batch command can only manage _integer numbers_...

Comment: @Aacini OP was tagged incorrectly, this is not a `batch-file` question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just do:

```
B = A / A[:, 3:, 3:]
```

Comment: this was actually the solution! I was trying B = A/A[:, 3, 3] but it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeMoser The reason that didn't work is because `A[:, 3, 3]` has shape `N`, which cannot be operated with `N, 4, 4` according to [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you need the two last unitary dimensions. You could also have used `tf.expand_dims` a couple of times or `A[:, 3, 3, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]`, the result should be the same.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!